# How to use sqlLite Full Outer Join

Tags: android, sqlite

[queryResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDlbw.png) 
 [tmpOrderQuntity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKNXQ.png) 
 [tblSetItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgc4v.png)

I want Link Tow Tables In SqlLite With Full Outer Join (With Left Or Right Join)

I use MsSql server with Full Join It already Work With Correct Out put. but it does not work Sql Lite

SQLLite This column value is incorrect (CrStock - tmpOrderQuntity.OrderQuntuty)  parent  table (tblSetItem.CrStock) values are null , but child table (tmpOrderQuntity.OrderQuntuty) values are  correct

```
SELECT id,ItemCode,ItemDesc,imgPath,CrStock,CrUnitPrice,CrCostPrice,CrStock - tmpOrderQuntity.OrderQuntuty 
 AS 'AvailableQty',
0 AS 'ItemDiscount',Commission 
FROM tblSetItem 
LEFT  JOIN tmpOrderQuntity ON tmpOrderQuntity.ItemID = tblSetItem.id
UNION
SELECT id,ItemCode,ItemDesc,imgPath,CrStock,CrUnitPrice,CrCostPrice,CrStock - tmpOrderQuntity.OrderQuntuty 
 AS 'AvailableQty',
0 AS 'ItemDiscount',Commission 
FROM tmpOrderQuntity  
LEFT  JOIN  tblSetItem ON tmpOrderQuntity.ItemID = tblSetItem.id
```

(table : tblsetItem)

```
id  ItemDesc    ItemCode    WarrentyPeriod  Commission  ModelID CreatedDate ModifiedDate    Status  UserID  imgPath ShowInGallary   CrUnitPrice IsCommAmount    CrStock
1   Corless Drill Driver 14.4V (HDA5123L) test PRASA    5000    6   200 1   08:18.4 13:01.0 0   0       0   11813.05    0   1
2   Electric Drill 450W (HDA113)    5001    6   200 1   08:18.4 13:39.2 0   0       0   4217.4  0   12
3   Electric Drill 330W (HDA128)    5002    6   200 1   08:18.4 14:28.1 0   0       0   3782.61 0   22
4   Impact Drill 600W (HDA230)  5003    6   200 1   08:18.4 14:46.4 0   0       0   4739.14 0   2
```

(table : tmpOrderQuntity)

```
ItemID  OrderQuntuty
4   1.0
2   4.0
7   10.0
```

(Query Result Sql Lite)

```
id  ItemCode    ItemDesc    imgPath CrStock CrUnitPrice CrCostPrice AvailableQty    ItemDiscount    Commission
1   5000    Corless Drill Driver 14.4V (HDA5123L) test PRASA        1   11813.05    0   null    0   200
2   5001    Electric Drill 450W (HDA113)        12  4217.4  0   8   0   200
3   5002    Electric Drill 330W (HDA128)        22  3782.61 0   null    0   200
4   5003    Impact Drill 600W (HDA230)      2   4739.14 0   1   0   200
5   5004    Rotary Hammer 710W (HDA316)     95  10860.87    0   null    0   200
6   5005    Rotary Hammer - 800W (HDA310)       58  10000   0   null    0   200+AA1:J7
```

Comment: See http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-full-outer-join/

Comment: i tried this Tutorial but cant get correct some rows null value .  (tblSetItem .CrStock - tmpOrderQuntity.OrderQuntuty )

Comment: AvailableQty
null
8.0
null
1.0

Comment: Are these the actual results? How did you get ids 5 and 6? They don't exist in any of the tables!

Comment: (table :tmpOrderQuntity)  have 3 rows 
(table : tblSetItem) have 1397 rows  
i posted on some rows in result this

Comment: Use UNION ALL not UNION.

Comment: I tried  UNION ALL sqllite Result: 1400 rows returned. it dose not correct. (correct  Result: 1397 rows ). added  extra  this table (tmpOrderQuntity) 3 rows in result.  i use (tblSetItem.CrStock - tmpOrderQuntity.OrderQuntuty) return

Comment: If tblSetItem has 1397 rows then 1397 rows is **not** the correct result for a full outer join if there are unmatching ids.